# Avoid XML integer parse errors if field empty

Tags: go

Consider these 2 XML documents

```
<a>
  <b nil="true"></b>
</a>
```

and

```
<a>
  <b type="integer">1</b>
</a>
```

How can I unmarshal this XML properly in Go to a `b` struct field of type `int`, without producing a `strconv.ParseInt: parsing "": invalid syntax` error in the first case?

`omitempty` doesn't seem to work in this case.

Example: http://play.golang.org/p/fbhVJ4zUbl

Comment: You may want to make your own implementation of the XML decoder wrapping Go's xml decoder.  The `encoding/json` is much more powerful, you could take it as example.  If `json.Unmarshal(...)` sees that your types instance `obj` implements `json.Unmarshaler`, it will call `obj.UnmarshalJSON`.  I have no idea why the `encoding/xml` doesn't do the same thing.  You may want to repost your question on the [Go mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/golang-nuts).  Seems odd that making `b` a pointer doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

The omitempty tag is just respected with Marshal, not Unmarshal.

Unmarshal errors if the int value is not an actual int.

Instead, change B to a string. Then, convert B to an int with the strconv package. If it errors, set it to 0.

Try this snippet: http://play.golang.org/p/1zqmlmIQDB

Comment: Manually parsing it is not what I'm trying to do here. That is the obvious option anyway if the XML unmarshaller can't handle it. That said, I'll not pollute the struct with meta fields just for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "github.com/guregu/null" package. It helps:

```
package main
import (
"fmt"
    "encoding/xml"
    "github.com/guregu/null"
)

type Items struct{
    It []Item `xml:"Item"`
}

type Item struct {
    DealNo   string
    ItemNo   null.Int
    Name     string
    Price    null.Float
    Quantity null.Float
    Place    string
}

func main(){
    data := `
    <Items>
        <Item>
                <DealNo/>
                <ItemNo>32435</ItemNo>
                <Name>dsffdf</Name>
                <Price>135.12</Price>
                <Quantity></Quantity>
                <Place>dsffs</Place>
            </Item>
            <Item>
                <DealNo/>
                <ItemNo></ItemNo>
                <Name>dsfsfs</Name>
                <Price></Price>
                <Quantity>1.5</Quantity>
                <Place>sfsfsfs</Place>
            </Item>
            </Items>`

var xmlMsg Items

        if err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &xmlMsg); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error: cannot unmarshal xml from web ", err)
        } else {
            fmt.Println("XML: ", xmlMsg)
        }
}
```